# Calculate an upper limit of a probability without given variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I was wondering how you can calculate the upper limit of a probability using only a mean. Without using a sample size or variance.

Example:

> The average score for a test is 60 out of 100.
>
> Calculate the upper limit for the probability that a student will score **more than** 80 out of a 100.

The answer is apparently $\frac{3}{4}$ but I cannot find any explanation how this is calculated.

Every explanation that I can find online always uses a mean, variance and some sort of distribution. In this example you have only a mean and yet somehow it is still possible to find an answer.

Am I missing something super obvious or is the writer of this exercise breaking a fundamental law?

Comment: Hint:  use the fact that the lowest possible score is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I must really be missing some sort of fundamentals about this because I really don't understand where you get that formula from. Why does it matter what the lowest possible score is, and why would we multiply it by the inverse chance? And how can we guarantee that in this case 60 is larger or equal to $80p$?

Comment: If the test score could be $-10^6$ then you could have $p≈0.99998$ (just imagine that $80$ and $-10^6$ were the only possible scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Markov's Inequality (proof similar to Chebyshev, see Wikipedia on 'Markov Inequality') states: For a random variable $X$ with $P(X > 0) = 1$ and
$E(X) = \mu,$
$$P(X \ge a) \le \mu/a.$$
Use $\mu = 60,\, a = 80$ to get the stated answer.

Because this inequality holds for a large variety of distributions, you
can't expect the bound to be very good in general. For example, if
$Y$ is normal with $\mu = 60,\,\sigma = 10,$ we would have $P(Y \ge 80)  \approx  0.023 < .75.$ [Technically, to apply Markov's Inequality here, the normal
distribution would have to be truncated to ignore the tiny probability
$P(Y < 0).]$

**Addendum:** Sketch of proof for a continuous density. Proof for a
discrete distribution is similar, but using sums instead of integrals:

$$\mu = E(X) = \int_0^\infty xf_x(x)\,dx \ge \int_a^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx
 \ge \int_0^a af_X(x)\,dx
= aP(X \ge a).$$

Notice that the first inequality uses the assumption that $P(X > 0) = 1.$

Comment: Thanks! This seems to make sense. I'll have a closer look at Markov then to make sure I understand it. Strange that I hadn't stumbled upon it during my searches.

Comment: Chebyshev's Inequalty can be derived from Markov's by taking $X= (Y-\mu)^2 \ge 0$ and finding $Var(Y) = E(X).$ In turn, one or the other can be used to prove WLLN. Maybe look in your text for proof of Law of Large Numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that test scores are bounded below by $0$.  Let $p_i$ be the probability of getting a score of $i$.  Then $$60=\sum ip_i≥80p+\sum_{i< 80} 0p_i=80p\implies p≤\frac 34$$

Note:  this is the best possible bound.  If we imagine that there are only two possible scores, $0,80$, and we set $p=\frac 34$ the bound is realized.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand about this method is: 1) how are we able to say with certainty that 60 ≥ $80p$, 2) Since the question revolves around a score of 80 or more, how come we only need to take 80 into account and multiply the rest by zero instead of also taking 80, 81, 82, etc. into account as well.

Comment: $i≥80\implies ip_i>80p_i$.  Informally, my inequality replaces every number from $80$ to $100$ with $80$ and drops every number $<80$ down to $0$.  Clearly that can only lower the sum.

Comment: Worth noting, I have written all this as a sum (assuming that test scores must be integers) but there's no difficulty re-writing it all as an integral if you want to consider continuous distributions.  Doesn't change the argument.

Comment: Nice idea to try discrete version (+1)

Comment: Alright so I guess that makes sense. But if I wanted to find the bound for "a score more than 50 out of a 100", then $60 / 50$ would give a probability greater than 1. Or is this method simply not suitable for when the range intersects the mean?

Comment: There is no non-trivial bound for that.  If $60$ is the only possible test score then the average score is $60$ and $P(X>50)=1$.